# LSTM on sequential data, predicting a discrete column

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, classification, lstm

I am new to ML and only scratching its surface so I apologize if my question makes no sense.

I have a sequence of *continuous* measurements for some object (capturing its weight, size, temperature,...) and a *discrete* column determining the property of the object (a finite range of integers, say 0,1,2). This is the column that I would like to predict.

The data in question is indeed a sequence since the value of the property column may vary depending on the context surrounding it and there may also be some cycical properties to the sequence itself. In short: the order of the data matters to me.

A small example is represented by the following table

[image]

Note that there are two rows containing equal data yet having a different value in the Property field. The idea is that the value of the property field may depend on the previous rows and hence the order of the rows is important.

My question is, what kind of approach/tools/techniques should I use to tackle this problem?

I am aware of classification algorithms but somehow I don't think they apply here given that the data in question is sequential and I wouldn't want to ignore this property.

I tried using Keras LSTM and pretend the Property column is continuous as well. However the predictions I obtain in this way are usually just a constant decimal value that makes no sense in this context.

What would be the best way to tackle this type of problem?

Comment: Why do you need deep learning for this - couldn't you just use logistic regression? Also, I don't understand how your continuous variables are different from your discrete ones. Do you mean that the latter are categorical?

Comment: If property has a fixes range of values, treat it as a classification label and do multi-label classification. You talk of sequences, but in your data I don't see any. You have several features for each record, but all of them appear once. Time series are a different thing, throw out RNNs and stick to normal classifiers (either deep or, as Josh suggests, simpler models)

Comment: @GPhilo Thanks for the response. The point of the data being a sequence is that the order of the data matters. For example in the table you see two rows with identical data and different property value. The idea is that this property value depends also on the previous rows.

Comment: @JoshFriedlander I am not sure, I am trying to learn what is the best option here. Yes the Property field is categorical, there is a finite number of values it can take. My motivation for using deep learning was that I found examples for processing time series, which the above example represents.

Comment: You might want to look into AR or ARIMA, which are tools for modelling time-series data.

Comment: @JoshFriedlander The author of this article https://machinelearningmastery.com/arima-for-time-series-forecasting-with-python/ seems to suggest in the comments that a neural network model may be best in this case, given that ther are multiple data and the prediction is categorical?

Comment: Yeah, if I understand you correctly this is a multivariate time-series classification problem, and that probably is something that an RNN/LSTM would be good for. It's above my paygrade for now..

Comment: How much data do you have?

Comment: @Digital-Thinking Pretty much limitless as I can try different sampling times (seconds, minutes, hours)

Comment: In that case, yes you could go for an LSTM, where you need to define a window (max seq length) to look at and try to predict your sequence of rows.

Comment: @Digital-Thinking Right, this is what I am doing right now. The problem is that the predicted values are usually some kind of constant average like 0.34322. I am not sure if its possible to specifiy to Keras/TF that the predicted values are supposed to be in the finite domain [0,1,2]?

Comment: @Jernej  Do you mind a code sample in TensorFlow? or you would prefer Keras?

Comment: @EkabaBisong Do you want me to post an example or you have a sample to show?

Comment: I believe I can use the example in the question as a sample dataset?
Yes. Go ahead and post a code-sample if you have one.
Nonetheless, I'll give a sample with TensorFlow proper.

Comment: @EkabaBisong Yes, if you can provide a working sample that would be amazing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

df = pd.DataFrame({'Temperature': [183, 10.7, 24.3, 10.7],
                   'Weight': [8, 11.2, 14, 11.2],
                   'Size': [3.97, 7.88, 11, 7.88],
                   'Property': [0,1,2,0]})

# print first 5 rows
df.head()

# adjust target(t) to depend on input (t-1)
df.Property = df.Property.shift(-1)

# parameters
time_steps = 1
inputs = 3
outputs = 1

# remove nans as a result of the shifted values
df = df.iloc[:-1,:]

# convert to numoy
df = df.values
```

### data pre-processing

```
# center and scale
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))    
df = scaler.fit_transform(df)

# X_y_split
train_X = df[:, 1:]
train_y = df[:, 0]

# reshape input to 3D array
train_X = train_X[:,None,:]

# reshape output to 1D array
train_y = np.reshape(train_y, (-1,outputs))
```

### model parameters

```
learning_rate = 0.001
epochs = 500
batch_size = int(train_X.shape[0]/2)
length = train_X.shape[0]
display = 100
neurons = 100

# clear graph (if any) before running
tf.reset_default_graph()

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, time_steps, inputs])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, outputs])

# LSTM Cell
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=neurons, activation=tf.nn.relu)
cell_outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)

# pass into Dense layer
stacked_outputs = tf.reshape(cell_outputs, [-1, neurons])
out = tf.layers.dense(inputs=stacked_outputs, units=outputs)

# squared error loss or cost function for linear regression
loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=y, predictions=out)
# optimizer to minimize cost
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

### execute in Session

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # initialize all variables
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    # Train the model
    for steps in range(epochs):
        mini_batch = zip(range(0, length, batch_size),
                   range(batch_size, length+1, batch_size))

        # train data in mini-batches
        for (start, end) in mini_batch:
            sess.run(training_op, feed_dict = {X: train_X[start:end,:,:],
                                               y: train_y[start:end,:]})

        # print training performance 
        if (steps+1) % display == 0:
            # evaluate loss function on training set
            loss_fn = loss.eval(feed_dict = {X: train_X, y: train_y})
            print('Step: {}  \tTraining loss (mse): {}'.format((steps+1), loss_fn))

    # Test model
    y_pred = sess.run(out, feed_dict={X: train_X})

    plt.title("LSTM RNN Model", fontsize=12)
    plt.plot(train_y, "b--", markersize=10, label="targets")
    plt.plot(y_pred, "k--", markersize=10, label=" prediction")
    plt.legend()
    plt.xlabel("Period")

'Output':
Step: 100       Training loss (mse): 0.15871836245059967
Step: 200       Training loss (mse): 0.03062588907778263
Step: 300       Training loss (mse): 0.0003023963945452124
Step: 400       Training loss (mse): 1.7712079625198385e-07
Step: 500       Training loss (mse): 8.750407516633363e-12
```

[image: LSTM Model Prediction]

**Assumptions**

- I assumed that the target `Property` is the output for the sequence of inputs after 1 time step.
- If this is not the case, the sequence format of the data input/output can easily be remodeled to fit the problem use-case more correctly. I think the general idea here is to show how to address the multi-variate time-series prediction sequence problem with tensorflow.

## Update: Classification variant

The code below models the use-case as a classification problem where RNN algorithm attempts to predict the class membership of a particular input sequence.

Again, I make the assumption that the target `(t), depends on the input sequence`t-1`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, OneHotEncoder

df = pd.DataFrame({'Temperature': [183, 10.7, 24.3, 10.7],
                   'Weight': [8, 11.2, 14, 11.2],
                   'Size': [3.97, 7.88, 11, 7.88],
                   'Property': [0,1,2,0]})

# print first 5 rows
df.head()

# adjust target(t) to depend on input (t-1)
df.Property = df.Property.shift(-1)

# parameters
time_steps = 1
inputs = 3
outputs = 3

# remove nans as a result of the shifted values
df = df.iloc[:-1,:]

# convert to numpy
df = df.values
```

### data pre-processing

```
# X_y_split
train_X = df[:, 1:]
train_y = df[:, 0]

# center and scale
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))    
train_X = scaler.fit_transform(train_X)

# reshape input to 3D array
train_X = train_X[:,None,:]

# one-hot encode the outputs
onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder()
encode_categorical = train_y.reshape(len(train_y), 1)
train_y = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(encode_categorical).toarray()
```

### model parameters

```
learning_rate = 0.001
epochs = 500
batch_size = int(train_X.shape[0]/2)
length = train_X.shape[0]
display = 100
neurons = 100

# clear graph (if any) before running
tf.reset_default_graph()

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, time_steps, inputs])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, outputs])

# LSTM Cell
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=neurons, activation=tf.nn.relu)
cell_outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)

# pass into Dense layer
stacked_outputs = tf.reshape(cell_outputs, [-1, neurons])
out = tf.layers.dense(inputs=stacked_outputs, units=outputs)

# squared error loss or cost function for linear regression
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(
        labels=y, logits=out))

# optimizer to minimize cost
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

### define classification evaluation metrics

```
accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels =  tf.argmax(y, 1),
                          predictions = tf.argmax(out, 1),
                          name = "accuracy")
precision = tf.metrics.precision(labels=tf.argmax(y, 1),
                                 predictions=tf.argmax(out, 1),
                                 name="precision")
recall = tf.metrics.recall(labels=tf.argmax(y, 1),
                           predictions=tf.argmax(out, 1),
                           name="recall")
f1 = 2 * accuracy[1] * recall[1] / ( precision[1] + recall[1] )
```

### execute in Session

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # initialize all variables
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    tf.local_variables_initializer().run()

    # Train the model
    for steps in range(epochs):
        mini_batch = zip(range(0, length, batch_size),
                   range(batch_size, length+1, batch_size))

        # train data in mini-batches
        for (start, end) in mini_batch:
            sess.run(training_op, feed_dict = {X: train_X[start:end,:,:],
                                               y: train_y[start:end,:]})

        # print training performance 
        if (steps+1) % display == 0:
            # evaluate loss function on training set
            loss_fn = loss.eval(feed_dict = {X: train_X, y: train_y})
            print('Step: {}  \tTraining loss: {}'.format((steps+1), loss_fn))

    # evaluate model accuracy
    acc, prec, recall, f1 = sess.run([accuracy, precision, recall, f1],
                                     feed_dict = {X: train_X, y: train_y})

    print('\nEvaluation  on training set')
    print('Accuracy:', acc[1])
    print('Precision:', prec[1])
    print('Recall:', recall[1])
    print('F1 score:', f1)
```

#### 'Output':

```
Step: 100       Training loss: 0.5373622179031372
Step: 200       Training loss: 0.33380019664764404
Step: 300       Training loss: 0.176949605345726
Step: 400       Training loss: 0.0781424418091774
Step: 500       Training loss: 0.0373661033809185

Evaluation  on training set
Accuracy: 1.0
Precision: 1.0
Recall: 1.0
F1 score: 1.0
```

Comment: Ekaba, thanks for writing this. Some questions as I study your code. 1.) Is the (0,1) MinMax scaler scaling each column independently or will it use the same scaler for all columns?  2) Is there a way to let TF know that the Property column is an integer field and that the loss function is the ratio of failures to predict the proper class? 3) Finally, how can I see what Property got predicted for a specific row? I apologize for overflowing with questions, I am slowly trying to learn ML.

Comment: (1). The MinMax scaler "scales and translates each column individually such that it is in the given range on the training set, i.e. between zero and one". (2). Yes. we'll use the softmax cross entropy loss function to treat this as a classification problem. To do this, the column 'Property' will be converted to a one-hot-encoded array. (3). That's easy, we'll simply print out the variable y_pred. With a much larger dataset, we can easily code up a look-up mechanism.
No worries. I'm happy to be of help.
If you'd like I can update the code based on this discussion. If so, let me know.
Cheers.

Comment: thank you. I appreciate the way you are available and helping me out with your in-depth replies. I would appreciate if you could modify the code to reflect the discussion as I am sure to mess something up at this point. Also a follow up question. Does your approach take into account that the Property at step i somehow depends on the previous rows as well, or do I have to encode that into the rows myself (by adding previous values)? Also when testing the accuracy does the model make sure not to query the property for row i while somehow telling the model about row i+1?

Comment: I've updated the code for the classification setting, where `Property` indicates a class membership. This code assumes that the output `t` depends on the input `t-1`. It is possible to make the output dependent on previous time_steps of `t-2` and so on by modifying how the dataset is framed.

Comment: *Note:* I updated the regression version as well to deal with some observed bugs. As well as to reflect the assumption that the output `t` is predicted from the input sequence at `t-1`.

Comment: @Ekiba, thank you. A follow up question. Playing with your example I changed the temperature slightly to 'Temperature': [1, 1, 24.3, 10.7]. That is, just replace the first two elements with 1. When running the example TF raises the following error ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 2) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, 3)' Do you happen to know what is the reason for this? I'd eventually like to test the model on proper data.

Comment: @Jernej. That's strange. Changing the data to: `df = pd.DataFrame({'Temperature':  [1, 1, 24.3, 10.7],
                   'Weight': [8, 11.2, 14, 11.2],
                   'Size': [3.97, 7.88, 11, 7.88],
                   'Property': [0,1,2,0]})`
ran perfectly for me. Once the data shapes align, one should have no problem.

Comment: Yes it is odd, but since it is unrelated to this question I've opened another thread for this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51787125/tensorflow-value-error-when-chaining-content-of-data-cannot-feed-value-of-shap