# Tensorflow value error when chaining content of data - Cannot feed value of shape (1, 1) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0',

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

This post is related to the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51726817/lstm-on-sequential-data-predicting-a-discrete-column) question. The code above is taken from the accepted answer.

The program itself works fine as is, but if I only changed the values of the data provided from

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Temperature': [183, 10.7, 24.3, 10.7],
                   'Weight': [8, 11.2, 14, 11.2],
                   'Size': [3.97, 7.88, 11, 7.88],
                   'Property': [0,1,2,0]})
```

to

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Temperature': [0,0,0,0],
                   'Weight': [1,2,3,4],
                   'Size': [1,2,3,4],
                   'Property': [1,1,1,1]})
```

I receive the following error while executing the code

> ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 1) for Tensor
>   'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, 3)'

Nothing really changed structurally, so I am really confused by this error. The odd thing is that changing the values of the data may or may not trigger this issue. I've tried various TF versions including the latest and the same issue always occurs.

Does anybody know what am I missing? The full code example follows.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, OneHotEncoder

df = pd.DataFrame({'Temperature': [183, 10.7, 24.3, 10.7],
                   'Weight': [8, 11.2, 14, 11.2],
                   'Size': [3.97, 7.88, 11, 7.88],
                   'Property': [0,1,2,0]})


df.Property = df.Property.shift(-1)
print ( df.head() )
# parameters
time_steps = 1
inputs = 3
outputs = 3

df = df.iloc[:-1,:]

df = df.values

train_X = df[:, 1:]
train_y = df[:, 0]

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))    
train_X = scaler.fit_transform(train_X)

train_X = train_X[:,None,:]

onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder()
encode_categorical = train_y.reshape(len(train_y), 1)
train_y = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(encode_categorical).toarray()

learning_rate = 0.001
epochs = 500
batch_size = int(train_X.shape[0]/2)
length = train_X.shape[0]
display = 100
neurons = 100

tf.reset_default_graph()

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, time_steps, inputs])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, outputs])

cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=neurons, activation=tf.nn.relu)
cell_outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)

stacked_outputs = tf.reshape(cell_outputs, [-1, neurons])
out = tf.layers.dense(inputs=stacked_outputs, units=outputs)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(
            labels=y, logits=out))

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels =  tf.argmax(y, 1),
                                  predictions = tf.argmax(out, 1),
                                                            name = "accuracy")
precision = tf.metrics.precision(labels=tf.argmax(y, 1),
                                         predictions=tf.argmax(out, 1),
                                                                          name="precision")
recall = tf.metrics.recall(labels=tf.argmax(y, 1),
                                   predictions=tf.argmax(out, 1),
                                                              name="recall")
f1 = 2 * accuracy[1] * recall[1] / ( precision[1] + recall[1] )

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    tf.local_variables_initializer().run()

    for steps in range(epochs):
        mini_batch = zip(range(0, length, batch_size),
                   range(batch_size, length+1, batch_size))

        for (start, end) in mini_batch:
            sess.run(training_op, feed_dict = {X: train_X[start:end,:,:],
                                               y: train_y[start:end,:]})

        if (steps+1) % display == 0:
            loss_fn = loss.eval(feed_dict = {X: train_X, y: train_y})
            print('Step: {}  \tTraining loss: {}'.format((steps+1), loss_fn))

    acc, prec, recall, f1 = sess.run([accuracy, precision, recall, f1],
                                     feed_dict = {X: train_X, y: train_y})

    print('\nEvaluation  on training set')
    print('Accuracy:', acc[1])
    print('Precision:', prec[1])
    print('Recall:', recall[1])
    print('F1 score:', f1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Lescurel rightly pointed out, in a classification setting, the variable `output` should reflect the number of classes in the target variable.

Whereas in a regression setting, it'll reflect the number of columns of the target variables (assuming we are predicting more than one variable).

So given the sample input data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Temperature': [1,2,3,4,5],
                   'Weight': [2,4,6,8,10],
                   'Size': [9,24,9,9,9],
                   'Property': [0,0,0,0,1]})
```

The number of target classes is 2. Hence `output = 2`.

**Note:** Your posted code in https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tmXgQfm8GB/ works well for me.

Just observed that your target variable `Property` is the last column of the DataFrame.

```
   Temperature  Weight  Size  Property
0            1       2     9       0.0
1            2       4    24       0.0
2            3       6     9       0.0
3            4       8     9       1.0
4            5      10     9       NaN
```

Modify your code as follows, instead of having:

```
# X_y_split
train_X = df[:, 1:]
train_y = df[:, 0]
```

change it to:

```
# X_y_split
train_X = df[:, :-1]
train_y = df[:, -1]
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved it! What was the reason that it worked for you and Lescurel but not me? Just the internal ordering of the data structure?

Comment: Exactly. The internal ordering of the data structure was the case. :)

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is a classification network: It takes inputs, or features (*Temperature*, *Weight* and *Size*), and classify them into one of your classes : 0, 1 or 2. (*Property* field)

When you modified the original dataset, you modified the number of classes : from 3 `(0,1,2)`, you went to 1. `(1)`.

For the code to work, you just need to modify the `parameters` section of your code so it fits your dataset.

```
# parameters
time_steps = 1
inputs = 3
outputs = 1
```

**Note** : In this case, I find the the term `outputs` is a bit vague. I would have used something like `nb_classes`

Comment: Thanks. I have changed the naming as suggested and tried to run an example with the following data change https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/NM4bJGnB2b/ I still get the same type of error. Do you happen to see why?

Comment: I have no problem running your new example. Are you sure that you didn't change anything else ?

Comment: I don't think I did. Here is a full running example that still uses the old naming too https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tmXgQfm8GB/

Comment: Again, no problem to run it.

Comment: Thanks for trying. That is odd. Here I get the following output https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5YhJ84cPDq/ when running the pasted code from above.