# How to get dense layer output of LSTM in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

I am using Tensorflow for modelling an LSTM with a single dense layer. What I would like to accomplish is to obtain the dense layer output/hidden representations from the LSTM. I have checked that similar methodology is available in Keras, but how about doing it in Tensorflow? I append my code below which is specific to the problem (referring to [LSTM on sequential data, predicting a discrete column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51726817/lstm-on-sequential-data-predicting-a-discrete-column)) :-

```
# clear graph (if any) before running
tf.reset_default_graph()

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, time_steps, inputs], name = "Inputs")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, outputs], name = "Outputs")

# LSTM Cell
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=neurons, activation=tf.nn.relu)
cell_outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)

# pass into Dense layer
stacked_outputs = tf.reshape(cell_outputs, [-1, neurons])
out = tf.layers.dense(inputs=stacked_outputs, units=outputs)

# squared error loss or cost function for linear regression
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
    labels=y, logits=out))

# optimizer to minimize cost
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    # initialize all variables
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    tf.local_variables_initializer().run()

    # Train the model
    for steps in range(epochs):
        mini_batch = zip(range(0, length, batch_size),
                         range(batch_size, length + 1, batch_size))

        # train data in mini-batches
        for (start, end) in mini_batch:
            sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X: X_train[start:end, :, :],
                                             y: y_train[start:end, :]})

        # print training performance
        if (steps + 1) % display == 0:
            # evaluate loss function on training set
            loss_fn = loss.eval(feed_dict={X: X_train, y: y_train})
            print('Step: {}  \tTraining loss: {}'.format((steps + 1), loss_fn))
```

The code I have appended is specific to the training set, but I believe the process should be quite similar to feed in a dictionary for the test set. Is there any one liner/short code segment which can return the dense layer output (hidden representations of input data). Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are inside a `Session` context manager, this is the shortest way:
    `out_vals = out.eval({X: X_train})`

It is equivalent to this:
    `out_vals = sess.run(out, feed_dict={X: X_train})`

You don't need to feed labels for forward propagation (if you just evaluating the dense layer).

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and can see that out_vals comes to shape 17112 x 2. My X_train is of shape 17112x1x102 and y_train is of shape 17112 x2(after one-hot encode). X_test is of shape 4279 x 1 x 102 (after reshaping & conversion to 3D array) and y_test of shape 4279x1 (after one-hot encode). I exactly wanted hidden representations for training data X_train which is perfect, but why is this of dimensions 17112x2 and not 17112x1? Can you kindly elaborate a bit on this please?

Comment: `y_test` should be `4279x2` because `y_train` is  `17112x2`, but you're saying it is `4279x1`?

Comment: Sorry, yes, y_test is also of 4279x2. However, the confusing part is that why out_vals is of shape 17112x2? Is it the proper hidden representation of inputs from the dense layer in your view?

Comment: The output shape `17112x2` is correct. You want to understand why it has shape `17112x2` and not `17112x1`?

Comment: Yes please. I basically want to use the hidden representations to train a different machine learning model. For that purpose, I wanted to know that if I use out_vals of dimensions 17112x2 as training data to any Machine Learning Model, say SVM for example, will it be able to possibly predict the labels on the test data. I know this is a bit off the mark question, but for that purpose, I wanted to know why it is of 17112x2, is it because of the shape of the y_train and y_test, or something else?

Comment: yeah, first dimension is the number of data points. The second dimension is the number of classes in case of one-hot encoding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189836/discussion-between-jchat-and-vlad).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, like this:

```
_, d_out = sess.run([training_op, out], feed_dict={X: X_train[start:end, :, :],
                                         y: y_train[start:end, :]})
print(d_out)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a query, that d_out is of shape 4278 x 2 as I print its shape. However, my X_train is of shape 17112x1x102 and y_train is of shape 17112 x2(after one-hot encode). X_test is of shape 4279 x 1 x 102 (after reshaping & conversion to 3D array) and y_test of shape 4279x2 (after one-hot encode). I am getting confused as to why d_out is not of the same shape as training input? I want to capture the hidden representations of the input from the Dense Layer of the LSTM. Can you kindly explain this? –